# Optimizing query speed for large tables

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a CSV file in the following format

```
email;username;description
```

The file has around 10 million records.

I have created a table:

```
id          int
email       varchar(max)
username    varchar(max)
description varchar(max)
```

A `SELECT` statement that draws a single record takes about 2 minutes. After adding indexes through SSMS (both clustered and non-clustered) I managed to reduce the time to 9 seconds.

Is there anything else I can do to speed up these searches?

Comment: Post your SQL and the create definition, including any indexes.

Comment: Please provide actual execution plan

Comment: You should always use proper types for your columns. Username or email aren't going to need max datatypes, right?

Comment: Post your select statement that fetch single record

Comment: So, have you solved your problem with that csvs?

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes to your table structure,

```
    id          int          (primary key)
    email       varchar(max) (unique)
    username    varchar(max) (unique)
```

That should help.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use more relative way. Usernames and emails in a separate table, I bet they belongs to the same user (one user - one email and username) each user with unique id (F.e. user_id datatype int). With unique index on both fields. Email and username must have fixed length. In Final table store

```
id, user_id, description
```

Add Foreign Keys for emails and usernames table.

Comment: If the user id and email address are unique to the table then splitting into a sperate table will not improve performance.

Comment: Perfectly right! If so, I will definitely delete my answer as irrelevant.